# Fastest and most efficient way to fetch a record from Remote MySQL to iPhone

Tags: iphone, mysql

What is the fastest way of getting a single record from a MySQL database on the server side to an iPhone native app?

The return type is `NSString`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start by designing an API, which may be usable by other clients as well.  A simple possibility is a RESTful JSON API.